# Rails 3.2 + Rolify: Application breaks after installing Rolify (Bug?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have [this Rails 3.2 application](https://github.com/AzizLight/AgileBaboon) running fine. I installed [Rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify) by following the steps below:

1. Add `gem "rolify"` to the Gemfile
2. Run `bundle install`
3. Run `rails g rolify:role`
4. Check the new migrations, the new files and the modified files (generated/modified by the command above).
5. Run `rake db:migrate`

At this point, I try to create/edit a User and I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#create

undefined method `user_id' for #<User:0x007f8f21f168e8>
```

Note that before I installed Rolify, everything was working fine, so the problem comes from Rolify.

Here are the migration, the new file and the modified file in question:

The new migration:

```
class RolifyCreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:roles) do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :resource, :polymorphic => true

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table(:users_roles, :id => false) do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :role
    end

    add_index(:roles, :name)
    add_index(:roles, [ :name, :resource_type, :resource_id ])
    add_index(:users_roles, [ :user_id, :role_id ])
  end
end
```

The new model:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true
end
```

The modified model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  has_secure_password

  has_many :issues
  acts_as_tenant(:client)

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :username

  validates :username, presence: true,
                       length: { within: 4..50 },
                       format: { with: /(?:[\w\d]){4,255}/ }
  validates_uniqueness_to_tenant :username, case_sensitive: false

  validates :email, presence: true,
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
                    length: { within: 8..255 },
                    format: { with: /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i }

  validates :password, presence: true, on: :create,
                       confirmation: true,
                       length: { within: 4..255 }

  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, on: :create

  # NOTE: Used by SimpleForm to display the dropdown proerply
  def to_label
    "#{username}"
  end
end
```

You can find the rest of the files in the project in the [Github repo](https://github.com/AzizLight/AgileBaboon)

Does anyone have a clue where the error comes from please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is happening because the acts_as_tenant is (mistakenly) creating a validation for a `user_id` field on your `User` model. You can  see this validator if you run this code inside `rails c`:

```
 User._validators
```

I would recommend to switch to the [apartment](https://github.com/bradrobertson/apartment) gem which appears to be more maintained than acts_as_tenant.